# How do I get rid of space between x-ticks and axis in Seaborn heatmap?

Tags: seaborn, heatmap, styling

In a Seaborn heatmap (within Jupyter Notebook), I am getting extra space between the axis and the x-ticks, which I've moved to the top.  If I leave the ticks at the bottom, they are flush as expected, but I need them at the top.  I can't figure how to get rid of that space between the upper edge of the plot and the x-ticks.  I tried the padding setting in set_tick_params, but that only adjusts space between the tick and the label.

[image: Heatmap with ticks]

Here's a subset of the data to play with

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

axis_labels = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q5']
data = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan,0.14,0.01,0.00,-0.05],
       [0.30,np.nan,0.01,0.03,-0.04],
       [0.16,0.10,np.nan,0.01,-0.02],
       [0.14,0.05,0.02,np.nan,-0.04],
       [0.16,0.09,0.01,0.02,np.nan]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))
sb.heatmap(data, ax=ax, center=0, annot=True, mask=data.isnull(), 
           square=True, cmap=sb.diverging_palette(275, 150, s=80, l=55, as_cmap=True), cbar_kws={"shrink": 0.75})
ax.set_ylim(5,-0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(axis_labels, rotation=90, ha='center', fontsize=12)
ax.set_yticklabels(axis_labels, rotation=0, fontsize=12)
ax.xaxis.tick_top();
```

Probably something super simple that I'm missing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could set the tick length to zero to make them invisible? And then change the padding for the tick labels? The ticks themselves seem superfluous in this case.

Comment: The weird gap seems to be caused by `ax.set_ylim(5,-0.5)` instead of `ax.set_ylim(5, 0)`

Comment: Yep!  That does it.  I originally set it to -0.5 because it was cutting off half of the final cell.  Somehow I must have fixed that elsewhere because with it set to 0 that isn't happening.  Thanks for your help!